# Joining two given set of queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have two queries which are giving me a desired result.is there any chance to combine them into one. the queries are below: The first query is below:

```
SELECT c.cy_id,
       c.to_id AS tsn,
       se.x AS tX,
       se.y AS ty
FROM c
JOIN se ON c.to_id = se.ar
UNION
SELECT c.cy_id,
       c.to_id AS tsn,
       swt.x AS tx,
       swt.y AS tY
FROM c
JOIN swt ON c.to_id = swt.ar
```

The second query is

```
SELECT c.cy_id,
       c.fr_id AS fsn,
       se.x AS fX,
       se.y AS fy
FROM c
JOIN se ON c.fr_id = se.ar
```

Can I join both the queries and get the combined results with all the column names.

Comment: what is your problem i cant understand? if i understand correctly combine the first and second query. if you wants to combine means use the `UNIONS`..

Comment: I want to get the results from a single query which currently i am getting through two queries.

Comment: did you get the result..like below answer

Comment: No i did not get the result..

Comment: give table and field details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
SELECT temp1.cy_id, tsn, tx, ty, fsn, fx, fy FROM
(
SELECT c.cy_id,
       c.to_id AS tsn,
       se.x AS tX,
       se.y AS ty
FROM c
JOIN se ON c.to_id = se.ar
UNION
SELECT c.cy_id,
       c.to_id AS tsn,
       swt.x AS tx,
       swt.y AS tY
FROM c
JOIN swt ON c.to_id = swt.ar) temp1,
(
SELECT c.cy_id,
       c.fr_id AS fsn,
       se.x AS fX,
       se.y AS fy
FROM c
JOIN se ON c.fr_id = se.ar) temp2
WHERE temp1.cy_id = temp2.cy_id
```

Comment: This query gives me the below error:
The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns.
And i guess it will combine both the queries output and so my total number of coulmns will be a count of the two select queries. And i dont want that. i want a single query to return both the combined result in one table in column wise.

Comment: You mean edited query also gives you the error? How do you want to deal with different columns in these queries?

Comment: Yes the edited query gives error. I want the answer in column wise.
Example for the first query i get four columns with data and four the second query i get four columns,with one column cy_id being the same.what i want is 7 columns with all the data.hope it is clear @leo zhao

Comment: I am getting the values in column but also getting null values but what i want is to display the exact values in seven columns.the values i got is below
CY_ID TSN FSN TX TY FX FY
1 33 (null) 344 555 (null) (null)
2 55 (null) 566 775 (null) (null)
3 22 (null) 545 454 (null) (null)
4 44 (null) 3333 5555 (null) (null)
5 44 (null) 3333 5555 (null) (null)
1 (null) 44 (null) (null) 3333 5555
2 (null) 22 (null) (null) 545 454
3 (null) 44 (null) (null) 3333 5555
4 (null) 22 (null) (null) 545 454
5 (null) 33 (null) (null) 344 555

Comment: This is the result for mine second query:
CY_ID FSN FX FY
1 44 3333 5555
2 22 545 454
3 44 3333 5555
4 22 545 454
5 33 344 555

Comment: This is the result for mine first query:
CY_ID TSN TX TY
1 33 344 555
2 55 566 775
3 22 545 454
4 44 3333 5555
5 44 3333 5555

Comment: What i want is only the unique five rows with the corresponding values not the repeatation with null values..so can you help @ leo Zhao

Comment: I`m sorry for my misunderstanding, and I updated the query, I hope it is not too late.:)

Comment: Its working fine and i am getting the desired result within less execution time. thank you @leo Zhao

Comment: Can i cretae a view on top of the query you have given.
When I try to create view
like create view SS as and then the select,it is giving me the below error
View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
Can you guide me on that @ Leo Zhao

Comment: Yes, view`s select statement cannot contain a subquery in from clause, so you would be to create view for each of subquerys first.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  c.cy_id,
        c.to_id AS tsn,
        se.x AS tX,
        se.y AS ty,
        c.fr_id AS fsn,
        sef.x AS fX,
        sef.y AS fy
FROM c
JOIN se ON c.to_id = se.ar
JOIN se as sef ON c.fr_id = sef.ar

UNION                 -- UNION ALL may be better
SELECT  c.cy_id,
        c.to_id,
        swt.x,
        swt.y,
        null,
        null,
        null
FROM c
JOIN swt ON c.to_id = swt.ar
```

Comment: syntax error is there.
the error is below 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'c.fr_id AS fsn, sef.x AS fX, sef.y AS fy FROM c JOIN se ON c.to_id' at line 5: SELECT c.cy_id, c.to_id AS tsn, se.x AS tX, se.y AS ty c.fr_id AS fsn, sef.x AS fX, sef.y AS fy FROM c JOIN se ON c.to_id = se.ar JOIN se as sef ON c.fr_id = sef.ar UNION (SELECT c.cy_id, c.to_id, swt.x, swt.y, null, null, null FROM c JOIN swt ON c.to_id = swt.ar)

Comment: well, there was a missing comma.

Comment: it's working and i am getting the result..thanks @luis Siquot

Answer (score 0):

***you should try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b660/3***

```
SELECT 
A.cy_id, 
A.to_id AS tsn, 
B.x AS tX, 
B.y AS ty, 
C.x AS tx, 
C.y AS tY, 
A.fr_id AS fsn, 
BB.x AS fX, 
BB.y AS fy
FROM c A
JOIN se AS B 
ON A.to_id = B.ar
JOIN swt C 
ON A.to_id = C.ar
JOIN se BB ON A.fr_id = BB.ar;
```

Comment: this is not working..i am getting 9 columns while i want only 7 columns.Example for the first query i get four columns with data and four the second query i get four columns,with one column cy_id being the same.what i want is 7 columns with all the data.hope it is clear